# Combine HTML with React in a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm creating my portfolio site. It has two main components, a landing page and a blog. I want to build the blog with Next JS and the landing page with plain HTML/CSS. The landing page has mainly static content so I want to create that with html, css and javascript.

I'd like the blog(made with react), to be available at `blog` and the homepage `/`. Also, during production, having the home page at `DOMAIN.com` and the blog at `blog.DOMAIN.com` would be great.

I've done a bit of research and I read about micro frontends but I think it's overkill for a project of this scale. Are there any alternatives? I'm just looking for something nice and simple. Also, I'd like to use typescript with the plain HTML file so maybe a build setup for that would be great too. Thanks a lot, and looking forward to your reply!

Answer (score 0):

the standard way to do that is to use webservers (nginx , apache) and set alias for that subdomain
you can set blog.domain.com == domain.com/blog
read document about setting alias in your webservers that you are currently using it